Type is work. But it lose highlight tip for correct variant... Why? or How to enhance?
This is actual (simplified) example of some function lab
const lab = <
  T extends Something,
  K extends keyof T
>(k: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? K : never) => {
  return ({} as T)[k];
}

const test = lab<Something, 'fn'>('fn')

type Something = {
  str: string,
  num: number
  bool: boolean,
  fn: (a: number, b: number) => number,
}

It works as expected. But with screens below I show what I also want and don't understand why it is not possible.
Below some screens for sure that in general type is works.
allow str in generic placeholder as key of Something but error with argument ... so aka works

event if argument become str also error ... so aka works

allow fn and tip it in argument ... good!

yes, this is only one correct variant and no errors! works

But why it can't tip me fn at once? Or at least any of the Something keys aka str, num...?


Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.

(see prev comment) Once you fix that: TS just doesn't seem to do completion lists for generic type arguments when calling a generic function. This playground link shows what I'd consider a true [mre] here. I'd say that if you really care about this you might want to file a TS feature request. Or maybe you can refactor to use currying like this. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz, Thanks for advice! Also your example is more cool because is even more simple however yes -- my interest is
why typescript don't tip me correct answers if it can say that another ones are incorrect?.
and your answer:
TS just doesn't seem to do completion lists for generic type arguments when calling a generic function
Sounds correct... but for me still little confusing)
P.S. may be later I try to simplify also my question, images, etc..
Thanks in any way!)

I suppose I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance

You are looking for IntelliSense to auto-suggest a completion list for the generic type argument for the type parameter K when you call the lab() function.  But TypeScript's IntelliSense support doesn't provide such completions.  You can show this with a minimal example like:
const f = <K extends "x" | "y">() => 0;
f<"x">() // okay
f<"">()
// ^ abc "A"
// ^ abc "a"
// ^ abc "All"
// ^ abc "all"
// ...

Here it should be incredibly easy for IntelliSense to recommend either "x" or "y", but instead you get the full list of all string literals TypeScript knows about.
There is a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#28662 asking for this. If you want to see it happen you might want to go there and give it a . But until and unless it is implemented, you'll need to give up or work around it.

If you're willing to use values instead of types then you can curry your function so you specify the type argument for T manually and then the returned function will constrain K to just the types you want to support, and then you don't manually specify K; instead you just call the function with a value of type K, and you get the IntelliSense completion list for the function argument:
const lab = <T extends Something>() =>
    <K extends { [P in keyof T]:
        T[P] extends (...args: any) => any ? P : never
    }[keyof T]>(
        k: K
    ) => { return ({} as T)[k]; }


const test = lab<Something>()("") // <--
//                            ^ fn

Here you have specified Something and then you get fn as the suggested input for the returned function.
Currying is only needed if you actually require K to be generic at all; you might not:
const lab = <T extends Something>(k: { [P in keyof T]:
    T[P] extends (...args: any) => any ? P : never
}[keyof T]) => { return ({} as T)[k]; }

const test = lab<Something>("") // <--
//                          ^ fn

But this is a bit of a digression from the answer to the question as asked, which is: the kind of completion list you want is not possible without microsoft/TypeScript#28662.
Playground link to code

Thank you very much for such a comprehensive answer, @jcalz!
It is very useful for me both from the point of view of typescript (even far outside the scope of the question), and in general as an example of good design of communication, posting questions and answers etc.. I'm really inspired, thanks again!)
